# Mongoose schema for e-commerce product

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, rest, express

So I am coding e-commerce store just for fun and I got stuck. I would like to create products with variants and without it for example T-shirt which is black and has size M but also for example pen which does not have any options to choose (it's just black pen xd). My problem is to create universal model for products which will work with products which have variants and with products which does not have it.

This are my schemas

Product

```
import { model, Schema, Document, Types } from "mongoose";

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  categories: [
    {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "categories"
    }
  ],
  variants: [
    {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "variants"
    }
  ],
  options: [
    {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "options"
    }
  ]
});

export interface IProduct extends Document {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  categories: [string];
  variants: [string];
  options: [string];
}

export const Product = model<IProduct>("product", ProductSchema);
```

Option

```
import { model, Schema, Document, Types } from "mongoose";

const OptionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    values: {
      type: [String],
      required: true
    },
    product_id: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "products"
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export interface IOption extends Document {
  name: string;
  values: string[];
}

export const Option = model<IOption>("option", OptionSchema);
```

Variant

```
import { Schema, Types, Document, model } from "mongoose";

const VariantSchema = new Schema(
  {
    sku: String,
    barcode: String,
    product_id: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "products"
    },
    pricing: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "prices"
    },
    variation_options: [
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        value: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export interface IVariant extends Document {
  sku: string;
  barcode: string;
  product_id: string;
  pricing: string;
  variation_options: [{ name: string; value: string }];
}

export const Variant = model<IVariant>("variant", VariantSchema);
```

Price

```
import { Schema, Types, Document, model } from "mongoose";

const PriceSchema = new Schema(
  {
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0.01
    },
    discount: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "discounts"
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export interface IPrice extends Document {
  price: number;
  discount: string;
}

export const Price = model<IPrice>("price", PriceSchema);
```

Discount

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from "mongoose";

const DiscountSchema = new Schema(
  {
    discount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 0.01
    },
    end_date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export interface IDiscount extends Document {
  discount: number;
  start_date: string;
  end_date: string;
}

export const Discount = model<IDiscount>("discount", DiscountSchema);
```

So I would like to:

Be able to create product and if I want add variants to it (I want variants to be optional but my brain tells me that they aren't now because I can't create product without them).